# Formatting malformed data for JSON use in Swift

Tags: json, swift, malformed

The output from this query:

http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/AAPL/chartdata;type=close;range=1d/json/

gives data that gives an error for JSON handling with AFNetworking.  I was abled to download the data as shown below, but now need to get the stock data - unix times and prices - into an array for graphing.  I am new to coding so text parsing is an emerging skill.

Suggestions?

```
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.1/AAPL/chartdata;type=close;range=1d/json/"))

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    if !error {
        var string = NSString(data: data, encoding: 0)
        NSLog("%@", string)
    }
    })

task.resume()
```

Comment: The response is not JSON but JSONP. If you strip the function wrapper you should be able to parse the rest with your normal JSON handler and extract the data from the resulting object

Comment: The JSON seems perfectly valid, after you strip out the surrounding `()` characters.

Comment: Hint:  Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Also, learn to check your JSON with an online JSON parser such as http://json.parser.online.fr/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to use the callback function, you could just strip the outer layer as Hot Licks recommended. You should subclass `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` to accomplish this.

For full JSONP callback support, you may want to configure AFNetworking with [CDLJSONPResponseSerializer](https://github.com/clundie/CDLJSONPResponseSerializer) rather than rewriting your own serializer from scratch.